# If i want to get server.get("/[url]/") through server.get("/[url]/:params"), what should i do ? Or is it possible..?

Tags: node.js, express

Literally, I want to get server.get("/[url]/") through server.get("/[url]/:params").

Cause i don`t want to call two function like below..

```
const server = express();

    server.get("/products/:id", (req, res) => {
        const actualPage = "/products";
        const queryParams = { id: req.params.id };
        app.render(req, res, actualPage, queryParams);
    });
    server.get("/products/", (req, res) => {
        const actualPage = "/products";
        const queryParams = { id: req.params.id };
        app.render(req, res, actualPage, queryParams);
    });
```

Then what should i do..?

```js
server.get("/products/:model", (req, res) => {

    const server = express();

//i think something must be written here...

    const actualPage = "/products";
    const queryParams = { model: req.params.model };
    app.render(req, res, actualPage, queryParams);

});
```

Thank you for your Read )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you I would do it like lhis:

```
const server = express();

function handleProductRequest(req, res) {
  const actualPage = "/industries";
  const queryParams = { id: req.params.id };
  app.render(req, res, actualPage, queryParams);
}

server.get("/products/:id", handleProductRequest);
server.get("/products/", handleProductRequest);
```

Since those actions are repeating so why not make a function and call it when you need it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It can help my code more clean and clearly :)
Have a good day!